# Promise wont catch error on audio failed play

Tags: javascript, promise

if the user has autoplay disabled I want javascript to detect it and do something as an alternative. This triggers after certain element is added to the DOM dynamically.

```
var playit = audio.play();
if(playit !== undefined) {
    playit.then(_ => {// Autoplay started!
    }).catch(error => {
     console.log('cant play it');
    });
   }
```

but I dont get my custom error on the console, instead an error saying that the user has to interact. How can I fix this?

Comment: send your error picture

Comment: `functions.js:373 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`

Answer (score 0):

use async/await syntax:

```js
(
  async function test() {
    var playit = await audio.play();
  }
)();
```

Comment: Im using chrome and its not working. It fails to play and I cant see my custom error log